# Dividing a file and removing columns having all 0's in columns

Tags: r

I have a file like this, ( The file is basically a list )

```
"0000"
"ab" "0a"
"000000"
"0000"
"aba" "baa" "aab"
"cb" "cc" "bc" "00"
...............
```

Now, I want to remove all those rows which contains all 0's as well as those columns which contains all 0's in a specific row. For example, the output will be,

```
"ab" "0a"
"aba" "baa" "aab"
"cb" "cc" "bc"
```

Then I want to write this list to a file on disk. How can I do it in R?
This list is a result of execution of a function in R.
Result of:

```
dput(head(data))
list("0000", c("ab", "0a"), "000000", "0000", c("aba", "baa", 
"aab"), c("cb", "cc", "bc"))
```

Comment: You want to write a ragged table? Did you read this into R yet?  I don't think we have enough information here.  Do you want to read the file into R, change it, and then write it to file?

Comment: assuming you haven't read the data in, `read.table(..., fill = TRUE, sep = " ")` will likely be of use.

Comment: Personally, I think the terminal command line would be best for changing a file such as this.

Comment: @RicharScriven, this file is the output of a function that I exectuted. It is getting stored in a table in R itself. Can't this be handled?

Comment: This certainly can be handled, we just need to communicate about what data you actually have on your hands...why don't you paste the results of `dput(head(yourDataHere))` so we can actually see what you're working with

Comment: It is a list. There are no "rows" or "columns" in a list. Please clarify your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You input dataset was `list`.  So, I am guessing the output would also be `list`

```
  library(stringr)
  data[[1]] <- c("0a0000", "000000", "a00000")
  lst1 <- lapply(data, function(x) {x1 <- str_count(x, "0"); x[x1!=nchar(x)]})
  indx <- sapply(lst1, length)
  lst2 <- lst1[!!indx]
  datN <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind,lapply(lst2, function(x)
                  if(length(x)<max(indx)) c(x, rep(NA, max(indx)-length(x))) 
                    else x)), 
                         stringsAsFactors=FALSE)


  datN
  #     V1     V2   V3
  #1 0a0000 a00000 <NA>
  #2     ab     0a <NA>
  #3    aba    baa  aab
  #4     cb     cc   bc
```

Comment: Great thanks. But, how can I write it to a file? Can't I write in form of a list itself?

Comment: @Qin If you want to write this as list, one option would be to use `capture.output`.

Comment: I guess the code above doesn't remove strings having all 0's present in one of the columns in some rows.

Comment: @Qin Could you show an example where it doesn't work using `dput`

Comment: @Qin So I guess you need only the 2nd entry from that list element?

Comment: I want the second entry to be removed from this row since it is a string having all 0's.

Comment: Also, it will be great if you can give me some insights as to how can I convert this list into a dataframe. Thanks. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61792/discussion-between-qin-and-akrun).